# Will removing an outermost electron from the outermost orbital of an atom change the orbital geometry?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atoms, orbitals, ions

Does $\text{He}^+$ and $\text{He}$ have different orbitals?

Comment: Are you asking just about the ground states' $1s$, or excited states' orbitals too? The ion has smaller $1s$ because the nucleus isn't shielded, but it's spherical in both cases.

Comment: Both ground state and excited state